# Error: [ ] operator not supported for strings, when attempting to append to an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a script, thats a handful of `if-else` statements. That if there is an error somewhere It will append a message to an array. Since there can be a good handful of errors for whatever case. I dump them in this array to later list them to the user.

```
$outputMsg = array();

$outputMsg[] = "State not selected";
```

Which this worked just fine up until today, which at random I start getting this error.

```
[] operator not supported for strings
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: somewhere your array's been overwritten with a string, e.g. `$outputMsg = "new text"` instead of `$outputMsg[] = "new text"`.

Comment: Your code does not do that. _Somewhere_, your variable is made into a string. Find that location ;)

Comment: That was my first impression, and I gave it a super quick scan through, came up empty.. but going deeper, I have found where my array turns into a string at random, looks like someone changed something in the code, and I didn't know about the change, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments.. upon a deeper inspection of my code, it turns out that my array is being converted into a string, and despite that notion continues on, where once upon hitting another error to append to the array, that error occurs.

I appreciate the help. But it is now resolved I believe, if not, I know what I'm looking for now. The problem was about 100 lines up from where the state error is, someone added in a new error for a new field, and didn't make it append to the array in a similar fashion, they just made it a string.

Comment: Right above your `$outputMsg[] = "State not selected";` do a variable dump via `var_dump($outputMsg);` and find out what it is.